# Is there a way to catch a players chat input without an AsyncPlayerChatEvent?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm once again writing another Banksystem plugin, but this time with an ATM. I'm trying to figure out how to get a players chat-input after clicking on the option, to prevent clicking 100 times to deposit 50,000 Dollars on the bank-account.

I'm writing this Plugin with Paper-Spigot 1.14.4 and I've tried following steps:

- A `AsyncPlayerChatEvent` as a separate Class, which activates only when I register the Event with the Pluginmanager:

```java
Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new ChatListener(), Main.getPlugin());
```

- Creating a `private` `AsyncPlayerChatEvent` variable `e` with get- and set-method, and calling it in the method when I need it.

```java
String input = getChat().getMessage();
```

My current `chatListener()` Method:

```java
public void chatListener(Inventory inv, Player pl) {
        pl.closeInventory();
        pl.sendMessage("§6Please enter your amount:");
        String input = getChat().getMessage();
        if(input.matches("[0-9]+")) {
            pl.openInventory(inv);
            inv.setItem(0, new ItemStack(Material.AIR));
            inv.setItem(0, CustomHeads.customHead(CustomHeads.BITCOIN,
                    input));
        } else {
            pl.sendMessage("§cPlease enter only numeric characters!");
        }
    }
```

`AsyncPlayerChatEvent` get-method:

```java
public AsyncPlayerChatEvent getChat() {
        return chat;
    }
```

I expect the message of the player to be saved inside the `input` variable, after the message "Please enter your amount:" appears.

When I create a `System.out.println(input)`, the console shows nothing, including neither errors nor any warnings.

Comment: You want the users chat input only when he should tell how much dollars he want to get from the bank? Otherwise there shouldn't be any reactions from the plugin when the user is entering something in the chat?

Comment: @Xge absolutely correct. It's an Inventory GUI with custom heads and when you click on the head, the plugin should ask for an input from the Player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `AsyncPlayerChatEvent` and a `public static ArrayList`.

**ExampleChatEvent.class**

```java
public static ArrayList<Player> waitingForAmountPlayers = new ArrayList<>();

public void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {

 Player p = e.getPlayer();

 if (waitingForAmountPlayers.indexOf(p) != -1) {

  //
  // YOUR CODE
  //

  waitingForAmountPlayers.remove(p);

 }

}
```

Don't forget to add the player to `waitingForAmountPlayers` when you want to type the player the amount in the chat (`ExampleChatEvent.waitingForAmountPlayers.add(p);`).

Comment: What a brilliant way to solve my problem. Thank you very much.. I'll mark your post as solution as soon as I can :)